# Get parameters from a useState in Ionic React

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ionic-react

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a json to use later in a chart.

My issue is that using **useState**, it gets me a **never** type data, so I can't access fields.

```
const [myData, setData] = useState([]);

const url = 'url';

axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        setData(res.data);

        myData.forEach( e=> {
          console.log(e.name);
        })
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
      })
```

When i print the **console.log** the **name** results as an error because **Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.**

How could I fix this?

EDIT: I'm using Typescript

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I forgot to mention it, I'm updating my post now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the type of useState to be any so that while accessing certain fields within it which can be undefined/null which misleads the compiler into thinking that myData array values won't be anything but undefined. You can explicitly define a type to avoid this

```
const [myData, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

Comment: This is it! I tried different ways to define its type but none worked! Thank you very much!